# Is it okay to override equals on an android view?

Tags: android

I have a custom view that i've created and have a use case for overriding the `equals` method. Digging into the source i can see that `View` doesn't override this method itself, however i'm cautious of whether something in Android may be using the `.equals` method of `View`, and expects that behaviour?

Is this the case or am i perfectly safe overriding the method for my uses?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by overriding? If you are looking at doing your own comparison, go for it. There is nothing preventing you from overriding that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you would be safe implementing it yourself. I believe it's a more standard practice, however, to compare the tags of the views, rather than the views themselves.